# Where is the spark job of transformation and action done?

Tags: apache-spark, action, transformation

I have been using Spark + Python to finish some works, it's great, but I have a question in my mind:

Where is the spark job of transformation and action done?

Is transformation job done in Spark Master (or Driver) while action job is done in Workers (Executors), or both of them are done in Workers (Executors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Workers (aka slaves) are running Spark instances where executors live
>   to execute tasks.

Transformations are performed at the worker, when the action method is called the computed data is brought back to the driver.

[image]

An application in `Spark` is executed in three steps:

1.Create RDD graph, i.e. `DAG (directed acyclic graph)` of RDDs to represent entire computation.

2.Create stage graph, i.e. a `DAG of stages` that is a logical execution plan based on the RDD graph. Stages are created by breaking the RDD graph at shuffle boundaries.

3.Based on the plan, `schedule and execute` **tasks on workers**.

Answer (score 0):

Transformations run at executors.

Actions run at executors and driver. Most of the work is still happening in the executors but the final steps like reducing outputs is executed in the driver.

Comment: Hi, Ilias, thanks for the reply! I am still wondering why transformation  needs to be done at executors since it is lazy evaluation?

Comment: Hi Olaf, lazy evaluation means that the transformations don't execute if they are not followed by an action. The are going to be executed only after an action is called. e.g my_rdd = sc.parallelize([1,2,3,4]), my_rdd = my_rdd.map(lambda x: x+1) . The transformation is not going to be executed because there is no action.

Answer (score 0):

When any action is called on the RDD, Spark creates the DAG and submits to the DAG scheduler.

The DAG scheduler divides operators into stages of tasks. A stage is comprised of tasks based on partitions of the input data. The DAG scheduler pipelines operators together.

The Stages are passed on to the Task Scheduler.The task scheduler launches tasks via cluster manager.(Spark Standalone/Yarn/Mesos). The task scheduler doesn't know about dependencies of the stages.

> The tasks(**transformation**) executes on the Workers(**Executors**)
>   and when action(take/collect) is called it brings back the data at the
>   Driver.

Comment: Hi Gabber, thanks for the reply. so spark actions are done at Executor? but the task scheduler brings the results back to  driver?

Comment: @Olafapple transformations are performed at workers and whn action method is called the computed data is brought back to the driver